# How to get user subscriptions with twitch api v5?

Tags: api, twitch

I [found](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v3/reference/subscriptions/)
how to do this, but only for api v3.

There is no such functionality for v5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### They are all still available.

- [Get Channel Subscribers](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/reference/channels/#get-channel-subscribers)
- [Check Channel Subscription by User](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/reference/channels/#check-channel-subscription-by-user)
- [Check User Subscription by Channel](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/reference/users/#check-user-subscription-by-channel)

---

There's a list of all the major changes on the [overview page](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs), so you can just look there to see if any endpoints have been removed.

> - The new version of the API uses user IDs instead of user names to reference users.
> - The _links object was removed from all responses. Developers are now responsible for handling the paging offsets when polling the API.
> - Sub-second precision was added to time fields
> - The /games/featured endpoint was removed.
> - delay, background, and banner were removed from the channels response object.
> - For search endpoints, the q parameter is now called query, and the type parameter is always set to suggest.
> - The paywalled field was removed from the video response object.
> - The /kraken/chat endpoint was removed.

For reference, v3 is still available for use until [Feb 13, 2018](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/#which-api-version-can-you-use).